# Radio buttons change warning message

Tags: c#, radio-button

Hello i have got two radio buttons. One male and one female. The problem is that when one of them is checked(male for example) and the user tries to change to the other (female) i display a warning message to the user. if he press ok the [radio-button](/questions/tagged/radio-button) changes from female to male and everything it is ok. But when he presses cancel the radiobutton also changes from female to male. how can i prevent this? is there any way to disable radiobutton_checked listener and enable whenever i want?
the code for the male and female listeners is the next:

```
private void NewTrdButtonMale_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
//if there are participants for deletion i display a warning message that says that if you change from female to male the deletion will be done
        if (newAreParticipantsForDeletion())
        {
            switch (warningMessage())
            {
                case "OK":
                    //nothing useful for you here
                    break;
                case "Cancel":
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //nothing interesting here
        }

    }

    private void NewTrdButtonFemale_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //it is the same code as the above but it is for female
    }
```

the above methods are the listeners for the radiobuttons. That what i want to do is that if the users presses cancel no change to be done. But this is the difficult part because i am already inside the male checked listener so the change has already be done.

Comment: Could you please post your code?

Comment: sorry i posted it but i am not sure that it is very useful. it is wpf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution.

i have to put the next code to the cancel selection.

```
NewTrdButtonFemale.Checked -= new RoutedEventHandler(NewTrdButtonFemale_Checked);
                    NewTrdButtonFemale.IsChecked = true;
                    NewTrdButtonFemale.Checked += new RoutedEventHandler(NewTrdButtonFemale_Checked);
```

the above code disables the listener. after that i restore the female selection and after that i enable the listener again.